# Dbcontext with using-clause in Asp.Net Json-Call

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, dbcontext, jsonresult

I ran into a problem when switching from the Local Development Server to the Local IIS Server (ASP.NET MVC4) using the following Controller-Method:

```
  public JsonResult GetJsonData(string Context, string Language)  
    {
       using (KeyValueDBContext db = new KeyValueDBContext())
       {

            var entries = from u in db.KeyValues
                          where ((u.Context == Context) && (u.Language == Language))
                          select u;

            return Json(entries, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
      }

   }
```

Using the local server, I received data when calling the method from Javascript without a   problem. The method retrieves a collection of basically Key-Value pairs from a database   repository and sends them to the client). After switching to IIS I got an Exception   telling me that the dbcontext had already been disposed of (although the using clause ends after the return-statement). (NB: Visual Studio also was not able to find   JSONSerializer.cs for some reason, but only when the error occurred). Switching to the   following version solved the problem completely:

```
public JsonResult GetJsonData(string Context, string Language)   
    {
        KeyValueDBContext db = new KeyValueDBContext();
        var entries = from u in db.KeyValues
                     where ((u.Context == Context) && (u.Language == Language))
                     select u;

        return Json(entries, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
```

In both cases, this was the using-block:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Data.Entity;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.Mvc;
  using beepov4.Models; // project-models
```

My question: Is this an acceptable way to use dbcontext for the purpose of JSON-calls (and dropping the using-clause) or is there a particular downside or hidden problem I should be aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try reading the `entries` into memory with `entries.ToList()` before passing them to `Json()`:

```
using (KeyValueDBContext db = new KeyValueDBContext())
{
        var entries = from u in db.KeyValues
                      where ((u.Context == Context) && (u.Language == Language))
                      select u;

        return Json(entries.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this was what I was looking for. "ToList()" forces the query to be executed immediately and in this case diposing the dbcontext creates no problems. I had tried alternatives by casting the result into lists of custom types, but this is straight-forward. Thanks.